# Ubuntu 12.10 64bit not picking up my Ethernet

Tags: 12.10, networking, command-line

I logged onto Ubuntu to realize that my Ethernet connection is not connected. It has worked fine until now. 
Any help would be appreciated. 
Also, I'm using Realtek Ethernet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open a **Terminal** with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

`ifconfig`

You should get something like this:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:19:5b:5e:0a:5e  
          inet addr:192.168.1.5  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::219:5bff:fe5e:a5e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1884961 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1232492 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:4 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2569144356 (2.5 GB)  TX bytes:114877090 (114.8 MB)
          Interrupt:19 Base address:0xc800 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:4022 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4022 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:147433 (147.4 KB)  TX bytes:147433 (147.4 KB)
```

Notice how I have an inet addr defined. If you do not have an IP address then something is wrong, most likely it is a DHCP problem.

Can you ping 192.168.1.1 or ping 10.0.0.1? (Most likely your router's LAN ip is one of those)

If you can ping one of those, then you can see your router and you are not getting a IP from the router. This could be either your router DHCP not configured/setup or your system not requesting an IP from the router.

That is if you have a router.

In the Terminal type:

`sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces`

and add this two lines in the bottom:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Save the file and now, to restart your network, on a new Terminal type:

`sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`

Finally, use the below commands enable/disable *eth0*:

`sudo ifdown eth0`

`sudo ifup eth0`

Comment: Everything that you said worked and gave me back a response except for the eth0 commands. It is saying ifdown: interface eth0 not configured

Comment: @user128638 I updated my post.

Comment: Whenever I used the restart command, the desktop disappears and terminal is left open.

Comment: Restart your computer and try to use the commands `sudo ifdown eth0`

`sudo ifup eth0`